# How to force a UIButton to always be on top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` and a `UIView` that animates, sliding down when the `UIButton` is pressed. The problem is that the `UIView` obscures the `UIButton`. I'd like the `UIButton` to always remain on top.

I tried this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:categoryBtn];
```

doesn't work though.

thanks for any help

Comment: is your button parent view is self.view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After Add any `UIView` or any other view on your this mainview , after that just add your this  line for brings as a supeview for button

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:categoryBtn];
```

For Example on button action event you add any view then use code like bellow..

```
-(IBAction)yourButton_Clicked:(id)sender
{

   ///Add some code or view here and then after write this line here see bellow line
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:categoryBtn];
}
```

Comment: Would adding UIButton to Application Window itself be helpful? What are disadvantages of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is will work, but this is exactly the kind of thing "insertSubview: belowSubview" was added for.

```
[self.view insertSubview:myNewView belowSubview:_categoryBtn];
```

This allows you to add the new view below the button on the view stack instead of adding it above the button and then rearranging the views.